# HP 240 G3 Laptop touchpad problem

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

We are facing  problem with hp 240 G3 laptop. Touchpad is not working properly.
Needs to touch more surface on touchpad for work.
on Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop or 14.04 both laptops.